# How to style h:datatable

Tags: jsf-2, datatable

I want to display data like this with a JSH **h datatable**:

**1st OBJECT**

object.title object.date

object.category object.description

**2nd OBJECT**

object.title object.date

object.category object.description

....

So I need **multiple** **rows** (2 rows) in one column. 
But I have no idea how that works.

Normally, a `h:dataTable` displays data for every object row by row.

For example:
[image: row by row]

But Id like to display it like above but for every object. So each oh my objects must be displayed like above.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why not put two `<h:outputText...>` in one column each? So title and category in one column and date and description in the second... Sounds straight forward to me...

Comment: And you title does not match the question. This is definitely not 'styling'

Comment: @kukeltje Oh wow.. It works with just putting two <h:ouputText> inside it. Dont know what I've thought before :O I tried several thinks like separating it in two panelGrids etc. ... thanks! ...

Comment: Einstein once said: Things should be as simple as possible, but not simpler. Way before 'kiss' became famous. And still people think wayyy to complicated. Great it works.